# sorting numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to sort the array in one proc and than the smallest number should swap its place with the first number . than the second smaller number with the second number and so on...
My code sorted the first num and just rewrote the array afterward. I haven't used a "loop"

```
proc min
    push bx
    push ax
    mov si,bx 
    inc bx
    checkminnum: ; the outer loop for checking all the numbers
        mov al, [byte ptr bx-1]
        cmp [byte ptr bx], al
        ja smaller ; if bx> bx-1 keep on
            mov si, bx; the offset of the smaller num is saved in si
        smaller:
        inc bx
        cmp [byte ptr bx], '$' ; check when the loop should end
    jne checkminnum
    pop ax
    pop bx
ret
endp min
proc swap
    push bx
    mov bx, offset array
    repos:
        call min
        mov al, [byte ptr bx]
        push ax
        mov al, [byte ptr si]; si has the number of the cell with the minimum value
        mov [byte ptr bx], al
        pop ax
        mov [byte ptr si], al
        inc bx
        cmp [byte ptr bx], '$'
    jne repos
    pop bx
ret 
endp swap
```

Comment: We don't know exactly what `min` does since you haven't shown us that code.

Comment: Does that even assemble?  Normally `byte ptr` goes outside the square brackets, like  `mov byte ptr [bx], al`.  Or since the other operand is a register, it can imply the operand size: `mov [bx], al`; you only actually need the operand-size specifier on the `cmp [mem], immediate`.

Comment: Your `min` function is clearly broken, since it always considers the minimum to be the smallest of two adjacent elements. So the minimum of `1,2,3` would be 2 according to your function, since 2 and 3 is the last pair of elements it compares. Also, it doesn't take into account that the one of these may be the string terminator `'$'`.